# Child SVG element of SVG style not showing background color

Tags: html, css, svg

I can set the background color of the root svg element, yet cant seem to get it to work with decedent elements.

#### Styles

```
svg {
  background:#ddd;
}

svg > svg{
  background:#444;
}

rect {
  fill:#55c;
}
```

#### Makrup

```
<svg>
    <svg x="0px" y="0px" width="50%" height="50%">
        <rect x="33%" y="33%" width="33%" height="33%"/>
    </svg>
    <svg x="50%" y="50%" width="50%" height="50%">
        <rect x="33%" y="33%" width="33%" height="33%"/>
    </svg>
    <rect x="16.6%" y="66%" width="16.6%" height="16.6%"/>
    <rect x="66%" y="16.6%" width="16.6%" height="16.6%"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

background-color is not a CSS property that SVG elements support. All properties they do support are listed in the [SVG Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/propidx.html) The outer SVG element is a replaced element which is more like a normal html element so it does observe additional html properties when used as part of a html web page.

If you want a background just put a `<rect>` element with an appropriate fill and a height and width of 100% as the first child of the inner svg elements.